# JetBrains Rider "Reformat code" action (Ctrl+Alt+L) removes line feed at end of file

Tags: c#, .net, jetbrains-ide, rider

I am using JetBrains Rider version 2018.3.3 on Ubuntu 18.04.
I have enabled the setting `Editor -> General -> Ensure line feed at file end on Save`.
This works great when saving a previously edited .NET/C# `.cs` file.

However, when applying the "Reformat code" action (keyboard shortcut: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>) which also automatically saves the file after applying the code reformat, the line feed at the end of the file is removed again.

Is this something for a bug report or is there another setting to configure the reformat action to stop this behavior?

Comment: You can create a bug report in the official issue tracker: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/RIDER

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found the required setting.

Checking `Line feed at end of file` in `Settings -> Editor -> Code Style -> C# -> Line Breaks and Wrapping` prevents code reformat/cleanup actions from removing the newline at the end of files.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I would expect this setting to be under "blank lines" tab, a weird decision by JetBrains.